# Which method of GestureDetector is fired for a single click?

Tags: android, touch, gesturedetector

And what is the difference between onSingleTapConfirmed and onSingleTapUp? 
Where can I find a full list of all the gestures available?

Comment: Check this https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection see if it helps